# Empty plot with PolyCollection 3D Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, 3d

I'm trying to use matplotlib to plot the results of running my neural network with various numbers of nodes and hidden layers, and I've figured the best way to do it is to replicate [this type of graph](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html), so I can show:

- The accuracy (z-axis) over different numbers of neurons (y-axis)
- How the number of hidden layers (x-axis) affects these trends

From the demo I linked before, I tried to modify the code to fit what I was trying to accomplish, and unfortunately, I just get [an empty graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCXqD.png) I personally found the documentation of matplotlib to be very lacking, and the tutorial didn't have any description of how it worked, which makes this difficult for someone like me who has never done 3D plots with it before.

The following is the part of my code concerned with building the 3D plot:

```
verts = []
for i in range(len(z_axis_values)):
    ys = [0] + y_axis_values + [0]
    verts.append(list(zip(x_axis_values, ys)))

# Create a 3D plot
fig: Axes3D = plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
poly = PolyCollection(verts=verts, facecolors=[cc(color_options[i]) for i in range(len(x_axis_values))])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)

# Build the image
fig.add_collection3d(poly, zs=z_axis_values, zdir='y')
fig.set_xlabel(x_label)
fig.set_xlim3d(min(x_axis_values), max(x_axis_values))
fig.set_ylabel(z_label)
fig.set_ylim3d(min(y_axis_values), max(y_axis_values))
fig.set_zlabel("Accuracy")
fig.set_zlim3d(min(z_axis_values), 100)
fig.set_label("Accuracy over {} and {} in {}".format(x_label, z_label, data_set))
plt.savefig("plot_{}_{}_{}.png".format(data_set, x_label.replace(' ', ''), z_label.replace(' ', '')),
            bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

And if it helps to understand why this isn't working, I will detail the data used in the example I've been testing it on:

```
>>> x_axis_values     # Number of neurons
[2, 10, 20, 50, 100]
>>> y_axis_values     # Number of hidden layers
[2, 3, 5]
>>> z_axis_values     # Accuracies of all the runs of the neural net, testing each possible number of hidden layers on each possible number of neurons
[94.73684210526315, 92.10526315789474, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 92.10526315789474, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 57.89473684210527, 92.10526315789474, 92.10526315789474, 57.89473684210527, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315]
```

If I'm missing any information that might be helpful in trying to figure this out, please let me know.

Comment: Where did you find the line `fig: Axes3D = plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection='3d')`? It's a very strange syntax, you are creating an `Axes3D` object that you are calling `fig`, which seems confusing at best.

Comment: @Diziet It's standard Python 3 syntax for strongly typing variables. I did it so my linter would stop screaming at me. As for the name `fig`, it's just a bad variable name lmao.

Comment: @Diziet I would like to thank you for your answer. It's very well detailed and easy to understand. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some strange things in your code. I started back [from the example code](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html) you linked in your question.

If I understood your code, you have 3 layers, each containing 5 neurons. And you have 15 accuracy values, so I assume that they are organized as [5 x layer 1, 5 x layer 2, 5 x layer 3]. If that's correct, I would reshape your z-values to have dims (3,5) so it's easier to iterate over them.

```
z_axis_values = np.array(z_axis_values).reshape((len(y_axis_values),len(x_axis_values)))
```

Then you need to create your polygon vertices. This could be done very easily like so:

```
verts = []
for z in z_axis_values:
    verts.append(list(zip(x_axis_values, z)))
```

which gives us polygons that have the following shape (I've highlighted the coordinates of the corners with red dots), which is not quite what you are looking for.

[image]

What you want is a polygon that goes down to 0 (or an arbitrary value `bottom_val`). So we have to modify the code to add to points, one on the left edge and one of the right edge of the polygon:

```
verts = []
for z in z_axis_values:
    verts.append(list(zip(
        [x_axis_values[0]]+x_axis_values+[x_axis_values[-1]], 
        [bottom_val]+z.tolist()+[bottom_val])))
```

[image]

Once you get the right polygons, you just have to apply the rest of the code in the example.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

x_axis_values = [2, 10, 20, 50, 100]
y_axis_values = [2, 3, 5]
z_axis_values = [94.73684210526315, 92.10526315789474, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 92.10526315789474, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 57.89473684210527, 92.10526315789474, 92.10526315789474, 57.89473684210527, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315, 94.73684210526315]
z_axis_values = np.array(z_axis_values).reshape((len(y_axis_values),len(x_axis_values)))

#bottom_val = min(z_axis_values.flatten())
bottom_val = 50

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

def cc(arg):
    return mcolors.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)

verts = []
for z in z_axis_values:
    verts.append(list(zip([x_axis_values[0]]+x_axis_values+[x_axis_values[-1]], [bottom_val]+z.tolist()+[bottom_val])))


poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[cc('r'), cc('g'), cc('b')])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=y_axis_values, zdir='y')

ax.set_xlabel('Neurons')
ax.set_xlim3d(min(x_axis_values), max(x_axis_values))

ax.set_ylabel('Hidden Layers')
ax.set_ylim3d(min(y_axis_values), max(y_axis_values))

ax.set_zlabel('Accuracy')
ax.set_zlim3d(bottom_val, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Hope that helps.